# Pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)=x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Ran across this problem studying online:

Show that $f_n(x)=x^n$ converges pointwise on the interval $x\in[0,1]$ and identify the limit function.

Well if we have $x=1$ we get $f_n(1)=1^n=1 \quad \forall  n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then if we take the interval $0\le x <1,$ The answer says that this becomes a *power sequence* which converges to $0$. Hence:

$f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for each fixed $x$.

> What's the reasoning behind the power sequence converging to 0?

I've tried looking through my textbooks for this, but all I can find are examples of general power series, and of course geometric series.

I also found $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n =0 \quad(\forall x\in[0,1[)$$.

Is this why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x \in [0,1)$ ($1$ is **not** included), then for any positive number $r$, we have $x r < r$. Hence $x^n$ is a decreasing sequence, and so has a limit $\alpha$. Since the sequence converges, the difference between the terms converges to zero, hence $x^{n+1}-x^n \to 0$ which gives $\alpha(x-1) = 0$, from which we get $\alpha = 0$. Hence $\lim_n x^n = 0$ for $x \in [0,1)$.

If $x=1$, then $x^n =1$ for all $n$, and hence $\lim_n x^n = 1$.

Hence the limit function is $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & 0 \le x < 1 \\
1 & x = 1\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$0<x<1\Longrightarrow x=\frac{1}{a}\;,\;\;a>1\Longrightarrow x^n=\frac{1}{a^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to understand it. Take the logarithm,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log x^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log x$$
When $x\in(0,1)$, $\log x<0$, which means $n\log x\to -\infty$ when $n\to\infty$.

And when $n\log x\to -\infty$, $x^n\to0$.